# CSV to XML using xslt - how to have incrementing column name

Tags: xslt

I have this xslt to convert a csv to xml, works fine, except the  tag is the same for all columns.
I need it to increment like this

```
<row>
  <column1></column1>
  <column2></column2>
  <column3></column3>
</row>
```

when I use position() it renames all the columns to column1

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('column', position())}">
```

Here is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="LF" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <!-- template that matches the root node-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:call-template name="texttorows">
                <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform" select="/root"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template that actually does the conversion-->
    <xsl:template name="texttorows">
        <!-- import $StringToTransform-->
        <xsl:param name="StringToTransform" select="''"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- string contains linefeed-->
            <xsl:when test="contains($StringToTransform,$LF)">
                <!-- Get everything up to the first carriage return-->
                <row>
                    <xsl:call-template name="csvtoxml">
                        <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform" select="substring-before($StringToTransform,$LF)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </row>
                <!-- repeat for the remainder of the original string-->
                <xsl:call-template name="texttorows">
                    <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($StringToTransform,$LF)"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- string does not contain newline, so just output it-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <row>
                    <xsl:call-template name="csvtoxml">
                        <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform" select="$StringToTransform"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </row>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="csvtoxml">
        <!-- import $StringToTransform-->
        <xsl:param name="StringToTransform" select="''"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- string contains linefeed-->
            <xsl:when test="contains($StringToTransform,',')">
                <!-- Get everything up to the first carriage return-->
                <xsl:element name="{concat('column', position())}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($StringToTransform,',')"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- repeat for the remainder of the original string-->
                <xsl:call-template name="csvtoxml">
                    <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($StringToTransform,',')"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- string does not contain newline, so just output it-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <column>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StringToTransform"/>
                </column>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample csv:

```
<root>
3779490,916705,CS,60,34.89,Sauce/Cholula
5918104,918958,CS,6,20.63,Pasta/Fresh/Cavatelli/6#/Frozen
5064774,920723,CS,10,45.5,Cheese/Oaxaca
3422752,925230,EA,8,69.6,Chipotle/Powder/Ground
5955640,BB171,CS,30,50.7,Butter/Unsalted
5295326,BC110005,CS,6000,54.95,Oil/Olive/Finishing
</root>
```

Comment: +1: a well-expressed question. However: trying to read code that has to scroll both horizontally and vertically is hard. Suggest reducing indent and breaking lines earlier (check the preview). Not trying to be picky, but to help you get help.

Comment: Regarding your main question, `position()` does not return the position of the output element in its parent. Rather it returns the position of the context node in the context sequence (which depends on the context, naturally). Typically this is the position of the context node among its siblings in the input document (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)

Comment: I agree. I should have used a smaller indent. I just copied it from visual studio.

Comment: It looks like you are using XSLT 1.0 . It is helpful to tag your XSLT questions with either the XSLT-1.0 tag or the XSLT-2.0 tag. Although this does not answer your question, this library style-sheet may be useful to you, if you decide to upgrade to XSLT 2.0: http://pascaliburnus.seanbdurkin.id.au/index.php?/archives/17-A-Generalised-and-Comprehensive-Solution-to-CSV-to-XML-and-XML-to-CSV-Transformations.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though `csvtoxml` is being called with a large string and it recursively works it's way through that string. `position()` won't work in this case because you're not working with a set of nodes.

Instead you might be able to achieve what you're after with a counting param:

```
<xsl:template name="csvtoxml">
    <!-- import $StringToTransform-->
    <xsl:param name="StringToTransform" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="ColumnNum" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- string contains linefeed-->
        <xsl:when test="contains($StringToTransform,',')">
            <!-- Get everything up to the first carriage return-->
            <xsl:element name="{concat('column', $ColumnNum)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($StringToTransform,',')"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <!-- repeat for the remainder of the original string-->
            <xsl:call-template name="csvtoxml">
                <xsl:with-param name="StringToTransform" select="substring-after($StringToTransform,',')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="ColumnNum" select="$ColumnNum + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- string does not contain newline, so just output it-->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{concat('column', $ColumnNum)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$StringToTransform" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works great. Only a tiny issue remaining, the last column has no number.
<row>
  <column1>3779490</column1>
  <column2>916705</column2>
  <column3>CS</column3>
  <column>Sauce/Cholula</column>
 </row>

Comment: You'll need to concat the column number in your `xsl:otherwise` as well.

Comment: Good answer, but, please, avoid using `xsl:value-of` in the body of an `xsl:param` (or in the body of an `xsl:variable`). This unnecessarily creates a tree with a child text node -- creating this and obtaining its string value later is rather inefficient. In all such cases just move the `select` attribute up to the `xsl:param` and define it to have empty body.

Answer (score 2):

Although XSLT is capable of processing non-XML content, it seems to not be intended as a general-purpose text transformation tool. As a result, most of the tools available to you are about manipulating XML infoset constructs like elements and attributes. There is a little support for text strings, but not much. So `position()` is defined in terms of input nodes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Node-Set-Functions:

> The position function returns a number equal to the context position from the expression evaluation context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Expressions:

> the context position comes from the position of the current node in the current node list; the first position is 1

Since your input is just a text string, you are always in position 1. I can think of only one way to do this with XSLT. Transform twice. The first transform gives you the basic structure with un-numbered column elements. The second transform numbers the column elements. Because you are selecting nodes from an XML document the second time, `position()` should have the values you want.

Comment: John, While this answer is right in general, please, avoid making absolute statements about XSLT -- often, as in this case, such statements are not true. It may be difficult to do text processing with XSLT 1.0 (although using the FXSL library many difficult tasks have been solved), but XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 is designed to be used for efficient and elegant text processing.

Answer (score 2):

Although the OP is probably looking for an XSLT 1.0 solution, for interest here is an XSLT 2.0 solution. This solution requires you to download my [csv-to-xml library style-sheet from here](http://www.seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/csv-to-xml.xslt), which is discussed in [this blog entry](http://seanbdurkin.id.au/pascaliburnus2/archives/117).

With this as the input document, referred to in the style-sheet with uri 'gangt.csv' (use a parameter or adapt as you require)...

### gangt.csv

```
3779490,916705,CS,60,34.89,Sauce/Cholula
5918104,918958,CS,6,20.63,Pasta/Fresh/Cavatelli/6#/Frozen
5064774,920723,CS,10,45.5,Cheese/Oaxaca
3422752,925230,EA,8,69.6,Chipotle/Powder/Ground
5955640,BB171,CS,30,50.7,Butter/Unsalted
5295326,BC110005,CS,6000,54.95,Oil/Olive/Finishing
```

### Style-sheet

...this XSLT 2.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:clib="http://www.seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/csv-to-xml.xslt" 
  xmlns:xcsv="http://www.seanbdurkin.id.au/xslt/xcsv.xsd"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl clib xcsv">
<xsl:import href="csv-to-xml.xslt" />
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/" >
 <data-set>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="clib:csv-to-xml('gangt.csv')/xcsv:row" />
 </data-set>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xcsv:row">
 <row>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="xcsv:value" />
 </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xcsv:value">
 <xsl:element name="column{position()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

...produces this output document...

```
<data-set>
   <row>
      <column1>3779490</column1>
      <column2>916705</column2>
      <column3>CS</column3>
      <column4>60</column4>
      <column5>34.89</column5>
      <column6>Sauce/Cholula</column6>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column1>5918104</column1>
      <column2>918958</column2>
      <column3>CS</column3>
      <column4>6</column4>
      <column5>20.63</column5>
      <column6>Pasta/Fresh/Cavatelli/6#/Frozen</column6>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column1>5064774</column1>
      <column2>920723</column2>
      <column3>CS</column3>
      <column4>10</column4>
      <column5>45.5</column5>
      <column6>Cheese/Oaxaca</column6>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column1>3422752</column1>
      <column2>925230</column2>
      <column3>EA</column3>
      <column4>8</column4>
      <column5>69.6</column5>
      <column6>Chipotle/Powder/Ground</column6>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column1>5955640</column1>
      <column2>BB171</column2>
      <column3>CS</column3>
      <column4>30</column4>
      <column5>50.7</column5>
      <column6>Butter/Unsalted</column6>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column1>5295326</column1>
      <column2>BC110005</column2>
      <column3>CS</column3>
      <column4>6000</column4>
      <column5>54.95</column5>
      <column6>Oil/Olive/Finishing</column6>
   </row>
</data-set>
```

Comment: I know this is a 3 years old answer, but I need to ask. The blog entry does not seem to work and the library does not come with a license. Can I use it in a commercial environment?

Comment: @Slampisko I have updated the blog post link. There are no copyright restrictions. Please feel free to use it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're opting for XSLT in this case. It's not the first choice for string handling operations such as this, especially since your source data isn't XML, you're just wrapping it in a node to make it XML. A more obvious approach would be to handle the CSV via something like PHP.

In any case, to answer the question, if you have access to EXSLT (this is often available with XSLT processors, e.g. PHP's):

[**Runnable demo here**](http://www.xmlplayground.com/OQ10Kw) (see output **source**).

```
<!-- break into rows -->
<xsl:variable name='rows' select='str:split(root, "&#xA;")' />

<!-- root - kick things off -->
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='$rows' mode='row' />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rows -->
<xsl:template match='token' mode='row'>
    <xsl:variable name='cols' select='str:split(., ",")' />
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='$cols' mode='col' />
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<!-- columns -->
<xsl:template match='token' mode='col'>
    <xsl:element name='col{position()}'>
        <xsl:value-of select='.' />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm doing it in wcf using c#. The design is so, lot of xslts. So I decided to stick with xslt.

Comment: While it is true XSLT 1.0 is not very efficient for csv to xml conversion, I think it is not correct to generalise this to other versions of XSLT. XSLT 2.0 is actually very efficient at it, and XSLT  3.0 even has a native function for it.

Comment: str:split is not a robust solution. The problem is that on lines, it doesn't handle the variety of line terminators that are possible (CR.LF versus LF for instance), and on values it does not handle quoted values and double-escaped " marks, which are are common in csv.