# Detecting a URL within an XML field

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink, detection

Can XSLT, through scripting or otherwise, detect the presence of either:

```
"http://..."
```

or

```
<a>"http..."</a>
```

within a message field and style it as a link. I'm prepared for the worst!

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011669/csv-to-xml-using-xslt-how-to-have-incrementing-column-name In this example, the author parse text line per line, and use substring-after and substring-before

Comment: I've since found in an unrelated post that XSLT doesn't handle 'detect&format' like that as well as directly processing the XML. The best solution appears to involve processing the source XML file using something like a javascript function [Saxon .jar](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.4/). I guess I was expecting XSLT to be some XML magic bullet.

Comment: @Pres, Regarding your last comment: It seems you still haven't read my answer :)

Comment: @Dimitre. Many thanks for your answer. I had been away and think that comment was prior to your in-depth response. I've just seen this, so will read at the first possible opportunity. Thanks for providing such a definitive answer. I've only used XSLT v1, so will have to delve into v2 soon

Comment: @Pres, You are welcome. In case you have any additional questions, please, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**XPath 2.0 provides the valuable feature of RegEx processing.
Using this in XSLT 2.0+ one can write**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vurlRegex"
 >(http|https|ftp|mailto)://(\p{L}+\.)+\p{L}+(/\p{L}([./?%&amp;=])*)?</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(matches(.,$vurlRegex))]">
  <xsl:sequence select='"Warning:", ., " isn&apos;t a valid Uri&#xA;"'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

````
<t>
 <a>http://abc.com</a>
 <b>\`\```^^^</b>
</t>
````

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

````
Warning:<b>\`\```^^^</b> isn't a valid Uri
````

**Do note**:

The RegEx used may not be the most precise for matching an Url -- you can substitute this with a better and more precise one.

---

**One could express this useful lexical check in a more reusable form, using `xsl:function`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vurlRegex"
 >(http|https|ftp|mailto)://(\p{L}+\.)+\p{L}+(/\p{L}([./?%&amp;=])*)?</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(my:IsValidUrl(.))]">
  <xsl:sequence select='"Warning:", ., " isn&apos;t a valid Uri&#xA;"'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>

 <xsl:function name="my:IsValidUrl" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pStr" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="matches($pStr, $vurlRegex)"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Update**:

**Here I am using the expression reference to which was provided by Michael Kay in his comment -- this is [from a W3C Note published by the XSD working group, separately from the XSD specification](http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-URI-RFC3986.xsd)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vurlRegex"
 >((([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9+\-\.]*)
   :((//(((([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]))*@))?
   ((\[(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){6}((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])
   |(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])
   |(25[0-5])))))
   |(::((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){5}((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))))
   |((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})?::((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){4}((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]
   |([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])
   |(25[0-5])))))|(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:))?([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))?::((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){3}((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]
   |([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))))|(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){0,2}([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))?
   ::((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){2}((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})|
   (([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|
   ([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))))|(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){0,3}([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))
   ?::([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})|(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])
   |(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))))
   |(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){0,4}([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))?::((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})
   |(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]
   |([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))))
   |(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){0,5}([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))?::([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4})
   |(((((([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}:)){0,6}([0-9A-Fa-f]){0,4}))?::))|(v([0-9A-Fa-f])+\.(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~]
   |[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:))+))\])|(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])
   |(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.([0-9]
   |([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])))|(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])
   |[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]))*)((:([0-9])*))?)((/(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])))*))*)
   |(/(((([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])))+((/(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])))*))*))?)
   |((([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])))+((/(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])))*))*)
   |)((\?((([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]))|/
   |\?))*))?((#((([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@]|(%[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]))|/|\?))*))?)</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(my:IsValidUrl(.))]">
  <xsl:sequence select='"Warning:", ., " isn&apos;t a valid Uri&#xA;"'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>

 <xsl:function name="my:IsValidUrl" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pStr" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="matches($pStr, $vurlRegex, 'x')"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And if you want a more precise regular expression, there is one here: http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-URI-RFC3986.xsd, though it's very long and there's no guarantee that it won't break some regex engines. (There's also a variant at ./TypeLibrary-IRI-RFC3987.xsd)

Comment: @MichaelKay, Thank you. One related question -- why one can't use `xs:anyUri` validation? I tried with `castable as` and `instance of` -- the result was as if I had specified  `xs:string`

Comment: Basically, XSD got into a mess over the definition of URIs. There are too many definitions: absolute URIs, relative URIs, legacy URIs (leiris), "wannabe URIs" (strings that are URIs after %-encoding) URIs that conform to the generic syntax but not the scheme-specific syntax, etc. So they gave up in 1.1 and said anyURI imposes no rules.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Thank you. I updated the answer with the "official" long RegEx from the XSD Spec.

Comment: Actually, this regex is not from the XSD specification. It's from a W3C Note published by the XSD working group, separately from the XSD specification.