# XSLT 2.0 to convert CSV to XML format

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am are trying to convert an CSV (comma separated file) into XML. For this, I am coding an XSLT template and this is my 1st try at XSLT...

**CSV sample:**

```
ClaimRef,HandlerRef,ClaimType,Date,Area,SettleDate,ClaimStatus,ClaimantName
1,1/1,Liability,08-12-2013,US,23-05-2014,Closed,Mark
2,1/2,Liability,08-10-2013,UK,23-02-2014,Closed,John
```

**Desired XML Output format:**

```
 <Claims>
     <Claim>
      <ClaimRef></ClaimRef>
      <HandlerRef></HandlerRef>
      <ClaimType></ClaimType>
      <Date></Date>
      <Area></Area>
      <SettleDate></SettleDate>
      <ClaimStatus></ClaimStatus>
      <ClaimantName></ClaimantName>
     </Claim>
    </Claims>
```

I used http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2003/04/17/5780.aspx as initial start and http://xslttest.appspot.com/ to test the results. But this article mentions how to get the values as `<row><elem>, etc`.

Please can you guide me how to code an XSLT to generate above XML based on sample CSV data.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965790/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-xml-using-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option...

**CSV Input** (so.csv referenced in the `csv-uri` param.)

```
ClaimRef,HandlerRef,ClaimType,Date,Area,SettleDate,ClaimStatus,ClaimantName
1,1/1,Liability,08-12-2013,US,23-05-2014,Closed,Mark
2,1/2,Liability,08-10-2013,UK,23-02-2014,Closed,John
```

**XSLT 2.0** (Use either a well-formed dummy XML doc or the stylesheet itself as input or specify `csv2xml` as the initial template.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="csv-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string" select="'file:///C:/Users/dhaley/Desktop/so.csv'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="csv2xml">
        <Claims>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)">
                    <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)"/>
                    <!--Get Header-->
                    <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>                                        
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:variable>                    
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
                                <Claim>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                        <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Claim>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="error">
                        <xsl:text>Error reading "</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$csv-uri"/>
                        <xsl:text>" (encoding "</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$csv-encoding"/>
                        <xsl:text>").</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$error"/></xsl:message>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Claims>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Claims>
   <Claim>
      <ClaimRef>1</ClaimRef>
      <HandlerRef>1/1</HandlerRef>
      <ClaimType>Liability</ClaimType>
      <Date>08-12-2013</Date>
      <Area>US</Area>
      <SettleDate>23-05-2014</SettleDate>
      <ClaimStatus>Closed</ClaimStatus>
      <ClaimantName>Mark</ClaimantName>
   </Claim>
   <Claim>
      <ClaimRef>2</ClaimRef>
      <HandlerRef>1/2</HandlerRef>
      <ClaimType>Liability</ClaimType>
      <Date>08-10-2013</Date>
      <Area>UK</Area>
      <SettleDate>23-02-2014</SettleDate>
      <ClaimStatus>Closed</ClaimStatus>
      <ClaimantName>John</ClaimantName>
   </Claim>
</Claims>
```

**Update per comment...**

Here is the same example, but using a variable instead of an external CSV file. You can use this XSLT to test in other online test tools that support XSLT 2.0.

[Example on xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFu)

Comment: Can you share the reference of your answer please.

Comment: @variable - I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by share the reference.

Comment: Any reference article for this please.

Comment: @variable - I do not have any reference articles. If you have any questions or would like me to add any additional details on specific pieces of the answer, please let me know.

Comment: I see that in the answer you are referring to the file:///C:/Users/dhaley/Desktop/so.csv; So how do I test it via tool like http://xslttest.appspot.com/. Please advice :)

Comment: @variable - Oh I see. My answer is specific to an external .csv file. To test without an external file, you could add a variable and remove everything related to `unparsed-text()`. I will update my answer.

Comment: @variable - I've updated my answer with an example that uses http://xsltransform.net. You can use this at xslttest.appspot.com as well (I tested it there too).

Comment: The question remains - why use XSLT for that? It is clearly not the right choice of tool. CSV parsers exist in a host of more appropriate languages

Comment: @DanielHaley can you provide the XSL without the data please. I am looking for a generic template without data in the XSL itself.

Comment: @Tomalak in .NET what do you suggest? I can across http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/XSLT.aspx, but I need an generic XSLT template (without data within it. just the XSLT)

Comment: @Tomalak - I missed that part of the question. How can you say that XSLT is clearly not the right choice of tool based on the minimal detail in the original question? If the csv isn't complex, why not? I've used this approach multiple times to get an initial conversion from CSV to XML that I can then perform complex transformations on (within the same XSLT).

Comment: XSLT is a language for processing XML. Use any general-purpose programming language you like for processing CSV. Which one depends on your experience.

Comment: @variable - The data is in the XSLT as an example. If the data is removed how do you expect to test it on your suggested xslttest.appspot.com? What you could also do is change the `xsl:variable` to an `xsl:param` and pass in the data at runtime. You'll have to try it to see if it works. Also, be sure you're using a 2.0 processor in .net.

Comment: @DanielHaley: On the website http://xslttest.appspot.com/ there are 2 boxes. The one on top is for data. And one below is for XSL. I put my CSV data in the top box. I need only the XSL that I can try in the 2nd box. How do I use the xsl:param for this? Please guide

Comment: @Tomalak - Yes the main goal of XSLT is processing XML, but with functions such as `unparsed-text()` you are not strictly limited to processing only XML. This is very convenient when your target output is XML.

Comment: @Daniel CSV is complex enough (quoting, in-value linebreaks, escaping, nested quotes) to necessitate a parser. It is out of XSLTs domain to process CSV, even if you can bang on it long enough to make it work. It's like hammering in a nail with a bottle. Can be done, wrong tool nonetheless. I simply doubt the OP has made up his mind about why he chose XSLT.

Comment: @Tomalak I came across  http://thescarms.com/dotnet/XSLT.aspx which shows how to convert CSV to XML via an XSLT template using .NET resolver class... Hence I am looking for a generic XSL for this.

Comment: @variable - The top box is for XML input. You're not going to be able to put strictly CSV data in there. You could wrap your CSV in a root element and process the content of that instead of a variable, but why do all of this just to get it to work in that tool?

Comment: @DanielHaley Because the http://thescarms.com/dotnet/XSLT.aspx .net code is expecting a generic XSL template. It basically works similar to the xslttest.appspot.com. The .NET code accepts CSV data and uses the XSL template to give XML output

Comment: @Tomalak - I didn't mean that CSV itself isn't complex and some processing would be hard to handle (ex. quotes aren't, but line breaks are). I meant if you have consistent input that is not super complex, there's no reason to rule out XSLT. Also, I think you're 100% correct about the OP and the decision to use XSLT. It could very well be that XSLT is not the right tool in this case.

Comment: @variable - It looks like their XSLT is looking for a root element named `ROOT` which is what I suggested; wrap your CSV in a root element. Updated example: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFu/1

Comment: @variable - Are you also onkarsahas (the OP)?

Comment: No just found this interesting.

Comment: Apologies to the OP for the spam. Hopefully this answer will help in some way.

Comment: @DanielHaley xsltransform.net/eiZQaFu/1 is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: HI @Daniel, can you suggest me the code in XSL version 1.0

Comment: @DanielHaley It seems your link to xsltransform.net is no longer available (dead link) do you have an alternate source for how to handle this sort of conversion without using a file?

Comment: @JRSofty - I think this is probably what was originally in the xsltransform.net link: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpx

Comment: <xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string" select="'file:///C:/Users/dhaley/Desktop/so.csv'"/>

Is it possible to set linux path like /tmp/some_file.csv (java project) ?

Comment: @DanielHaley I found your answer really helpful. But it partially works when some csv data columns contains "data , otherdata". It only pick the value as "data. Could you please suggest what changes required to read such values? Thanks,