# CSV to XML XSLT: How to pipe escape

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xml-parsing, pipe

I am trying to convert delimiter separated data to tokenize and parse into xml using xsl. Currently I have this

**XML**

```
abc|"x|y|z"|gh|ij
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <client:SplitString>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text"
                            select="/client:CSVString/client:CSV_Value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </client:SplitString>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text/text()" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="$text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator"
               select="|"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <client:Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </client:Value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <client:Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </client:Value>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                                select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine for regular delimiter separated values, but fails on the pipes inside the delimiter. I have the regex for it to recognize the pipe inside quotes as a single value. But i am somehow not able to use it.

```
"([^"]*)",?|([^|]+),?
```

I want the result to be

```
<result>abc</result>
<result>x|y|z</result>
<result>gh</result>
<result>ij</result>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that since you're using a named template that you're stuck using XSLT 1.0. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @DanielHaley yes, unfortunately! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is check to see if the string to be tokenized starts with a quote. If it does, output what's between the quotes. If it doesn't, tokenize it normally.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <value>abc|"x|y|z"|gh|ij</value>
    <value>"x|y|z"|abc|gh|ij</value>
    <value>abc|"x|y|z"|gh|"x|y|z"|ij</value>
    <value>"x|y|z"|abc|"x|y|z"|gh|ij|"x|y|z"</value>    
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <SplitString>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="normalize-space()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </SplitString>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with($input, '&quot;')">
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring-before(substring-after($input,'&quot;'),'&quot;')"/>
        <result>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($value)"/>
        </result>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="normalize-space(substring($input,string-length($value)+3))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring-before(concat($input,$delimiter),$delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:if test="string($value)">
          <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($value)"/>
          </result>          
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string(substring-after($input,$delimiter))">
          <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="normalize-space(substring-after($input,$delimiter))"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<SplitString>
   <result>abc</result>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>gh</result>
   <result>ij</result>
</SplitString>
<SplitString>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>abc</result>
   <result>gh</result>
   <result>ij</result>
</SplitString>
<SplitString>
   <result>abc</result>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>gh</result>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>ij</result>
</SplitString>
<SplitString>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>abc</result>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
   <result>gh</result>
   <result>ij</result>
   <result>x|y|z</result>
</SplitString>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2C9/2

Comment: can you please explain what does this line does?
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="normalize-space(substring($input,string-length($value)+3))"/>

Comment: The second arg of [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-substring) is the starting position. I start at the length of `$value` plus 3 characters. The 3 characters account for the first quote, the second quote, and the delimiter.