# Java XSLT transform csv to XML

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt-2.0

Despite lots of thread on this topic, it still doesn't help here....

Is there a working example to illustrate the csv to xml transformation using xslt?

I'm using [XSLT 2.0 to convert CSV to XML format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295377/xslt-2-0-to-convert-csv-to-xml-format?rq=1)

THe source csv file and xslt are all taken from the thread above:

```
@Test
public void testXSLT() throws IOException, TransformerException
{
    Source inputText = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputFile));
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsltTemplate));
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslt);

    transformer.transform(inputText, new StreamResult(new File(outputFile)));
}
```

But still it says:

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text-available, [parameter-ref(csv-uri/reference), parameter-ref(csv-encoding/reference)])'.'
:Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text-available, [parameter-ref(csv-uri/reference), parameter-ref(csv-encoding/reference)])'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text-available, [parameter-ref(csv-uri/reference), parameter-ref(csv-encoding/reference)])'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1018)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:791)
    at com.ihsmarkit.product.dtccpvin.csv2xmlFXOutrightTest.testXSLT(csv2xmlFXOutrightTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text-available, [parameter-ref(csv-uri/reference), parameter-ref(csv-encoding/reference)])'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.FunctionCall.typeCheckStandard(FunctionCall.java:461)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.FunctionCall.typeCheck(FunctionCall.java:370)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.When.typeCheck(When.java:88)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Instruction.typeCheck(Instruction.java:41)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.LiteralElement.typeCheck(LiteralElement.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Template.typeCheck(Template.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.typeCheck(Stylesheet.java:654)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.createAST(Parser.java:412)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:483)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:977)
    ... 32 more
---------
Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(unparsed-text-available, [parameter-ref(csv-uri/reference), parameter-ref(csv-encoding/reference)])'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.FunctionCall.typeCheckStandard(FunctionCall.java:461)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.FunctionCall.typeCheck(FunctionCall.java:370)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.When.typeCheck(When.java:88)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Instruction.typeCheck(Instruction.java:41)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.LiteralElement.typeCheck(LiteralElement.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Template.typeCheck(Template.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.SyntaxTreeNode.typeCheckContents(SyntaxTreeNode.java:484)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.typeCheck(Stylesheet.java:654)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.createAST(Parser.java:412)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:483)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:977)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:791)
    at com.ihsmarkit.product.dtccpvin.csv2xmlFXOutrightTest.testXSLT(csv2xmlFXOutrightTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using XSLT 2.0? XSLT 2.0 requires `saxon9he.jar` and the Java code needs to load the appropriate `TransformerFactoryImpl` i.e. `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`.

Comment: No, i'm not using xaxon9he.jar....  isn't the below sufficient? import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

Comment: Please check the answer and the documentation provided in the link. That should help. You are using `Xalan` processor which does not support XSLT 2.0 and hence the exception.

Comment: Once you’re using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0, please consider upvoting the answer you linked to if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2 is not supported by the Xalan XSLT processor you are trying to use, you will need to switch the Saxon 9 (available in the open source HE edition on Sourceforge and Maven). Furthermore the API you use it meant for XSLT 1 with an XML input source, if you want to use that API you would need to pass in a dummy XML input. In the linked example, the CSV file location is supposed to be passed in as the parameter `csv-uri`. As an alternative, you can use Saxon 9's native s9api (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html) and simply start the transformation with the named template, in that case you don't need a dummy XML input.